# Expand delimited chararray into multiple tuples

Tags: apache-pig

One of the columns in my relation contains delimited values (such as csv), and I want to break them out these values so that I have an entry in the relation for every value (combined with the other columns which have atomic values).  For example, if I had the following data:

```
SomeID|Age|CommaSeperatedNames
1     |23 |Steve,Joe,Bob
2     |26 |Dan,Mike,Tom
```

I would like the resulting relation to contain:

```
SomeID|Age|Names
1     |23 |Steve
1     |23 |Joe
1     |23 |Bob
2     |26 |Dan
2     |26 |Mike
2     |26 |Tom
```

Can this be accomplished using just PigLatin and built-in/piggybank UDFS? Note: I have a hacky solution involving a UDF I wrote, I'd like to know if this is possible with just Pig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`TOKENIZE`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#tokenize) will split your names into a bag. Then, if you [`FLATTEN`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#flatten), on the bag, it will split it out, line-by-line. If `TOKENIZE` doesn't tokenize how you would like (it should work fine with commas), you'll probably have to write some sort of UDF that writes out a bag.

```
A = LOAD ... USING PigStorage('|') AS (SomeID, Age, Names);    
B = FOREACH A GENERATE SomeID, Age, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(Names)) as Name;
C = STORE B INTO ...;
```

Comment: I have verified that this code works as written on my pig 0.9.1 install.  (assuming ... filled in correctly, of course).